# How to update an existing list item during a workflow to capture the newest list item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I have a custom build list to store status updates on a project. To add a new item, one simply click + NEW ITEM, fils in the Infopath 2013 form and clicks SAVE. Then a workflow is triggered to convert some of the inputs. One of the list column (named LATEST) is a YES/NO column to show which status update is the latest update (so all should show NO except for the latest added update). In the workflow triggered by the + NEW ITEM submit one step is to lookup the current item in the list for which LATEST = YES and update for that item LATEST to NO. Then the next step is to set LATEST to YES for the Current Item.

However, the current item with LATEST = YES is not updated. (the new Item also shows LATEST = YES). So I end up with a status list full of Latest updates, while I should only have 1.

During the making of the Workflow I constantly get the warning that the lookup is not unique and that when more than 1 result is found that only the first will be used. However, in my case NONE of the items are updated!

So I have to questions:
1) How should I setup the UPDATE LIST ITEM action so that the current item for which LATEST = YES is updated to LATEST = NO.
2) Why is it not possible to update multiple items in one list based on a workflow. In my case I should only have 1 LATEST = YES item, so it is not critical when the lookup would work, but I can think of many cases where a new item triggers updates in multiple other items.